# Index-match/MaxIF function using Python

Tags: python

I hope someone could help me solving this python scripting. I'd like to do something similar to index-match function in excel using Python.

I have two data sets shown below: -

a) The dataframe 1 (df):

| Index | Node 1 | Node 2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ABBDD | DSGHSH | 164.35 |
| 1 | ABNEQY | ASFCZC | 125.40 |
| 2 | ABNERR | ZDCDBB | 150.40 |
| 3 | BANDER | DSVBDG | 0.00 |
| 4 | GDCHR | CVXSVG | 94.05 |
| 5 | GFRSA | ZFGDHJD | 94.05 |
| 6 | SRHNAI | SDWRWW | 119.70 |
| 7 | ZDCDBB | BANDERR | 148.20 |
| 8 | VBZ3VG | EWEWWE | 148.20 |
| 9 | SDZXZC | ADGSGSG | 125.40 |

b) The dataframe 2 (df2):

| Index | Node | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | SDZX |  |
| 1 | VBZ3 |  |
| 2 | AAAF |  |
| 3 | ADGS |  |
| 4 | DSVB |  |
| 5 | ZDCD |  |
| 6 | GFRSA |  |
| 7 | ABNE |  |
| 8 | ABBD |  |
| 9 | EWEW |  |
| 10 | SRHNA |  |
| 11 | BANDER |  |

The first data frame comprises of two longer node names and a value column which I'd like to copy to the second data frame if its shorter node name contains in either one of the node names in the first data frame. If more than one value is available, only the maximum value will be selected.

My desired output:

| Index | Node | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | SDZX | 125.40 |
| 1 | VBZ3 | 148.20 |
| 2 | AAAF | NaN |
| 3 | ADGS | 125.40 |
| 4 | DSVB | 0.00 |
| 5 | ZDCD | 150.40 |
| 6 | GFRSA | 94.05 |
| 7 | ABNE | 150.40 |
| 8 | ABBD | 164.35 |
| 9 | EWEW | 148.20 |
| 10 | SRHNA | 119.70 |
| 11 | BANDER | 148.20 |

I have tried several ways. First step, I reduce the Node 1 and Node 2 name to 5 characters. I understand this is not the right way as this implies that I'll miss out those Nodes with more than 5 characters.
I can't figure out how to use str.contains in join/merge function in Pandas to solve this problem.

```
df['Node 1'] = df['Node 1'].str.slice(0,5)
df['Node 2'] = df['Node 2'].str[:5]
```

In the second step, I wrote the following code. It can seem to do the job but looks quite inefficient. I wonder if someone has any suggestion to improve the scripts. Basically, I split the steps into two. I compare the node names in df2 with Node 1 and then Node 2. Ideally I'd like to be able to compare two nodes in df with df2 at once.

```
match_node1 = df2.reset_index().set_index('Node').join(df.set_index(['Node 1']))
match_node1 = match_node1.sort_values('Value',ascending=True).drop_duplicates(subset='index', keep='last').set_index('index')
match_node2 = df2.reset_index().set_index('Node').join(df.set_index(['Node 2']))
match_node2 = match_node2.sort_values('Value',ascending=True).drop_duplicates(subset='index', keep='last').set_index('index')
```

Any help/advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't the value of `SDZX` be 125.40?

Comment: Thanks Dani, yes it should be 125.40. I will correct it now. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work, now:

I started from scratch because you're only providing a tables not coded data simple.

**Creating DataFrames**

```
import pandas as pd
dicty1 = {'Node1':['ABNEQY', 'ABNERR', 'VBZ3VG'],
                'Node2': ['ADGSGSG', 'EWEWWE', 'DSVBDG'],
                'Value': [125.40, 150.40,  0.00]
            }
dicty2 = {'Node':['ABNE', 'ABNE','VBZ3', 'ADGS', 'EWEW', 'DSVB'],
                'value': None
              }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dicty1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dicty2)
```

**Data Frame *1***

| Node1 | Node2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABNEQY | ADGSGSG | 125.4 |
| ABNERR | EWEWWE | 150.4 |
| VBZ3VG | DSVBDG | 0.0 |

**Data Frame *2***

| Node | value |
| --- | --- |
| ABNE | None |
| ABNE | None |
| VBZ3 | None |
| ADGS | None |
| EWEW | None |
| DSVB | None |

---

Now, I had to concatenate both columns `[Node1, Node2]` of `df1` so, I can deal with them when I merge the dataframes.

```
cols = [df1['Node1'], df1['Node2']]
conc_cols = pd.concat(cols, names='Node', ignore_index= True)   # This's a 'pandas Series' I've to convert it into a 'pandas DataFrame'
rename = conc_cols.rename('new_Node')
new_df = pd.DataFrame(rename)
```

**new_df Dataframe**

| new_Node |
| --- |
| ABNEQY |
| ABNERR |
| VBZ3VG |
| ADGSGSG |
| EWEWWE |
| DSVBDG |

Now, I need to **concatenate** it with its values so, I've to duplicate the `value` column to equalize the values of **new_df**.

```
new_df['duplicates_values'] = pd.concat([df1['Value'], df1['Value']], ignore_index=True)
new_df["new_Node"] = new_df['new_Node'].astype(str).str[:4]
```

Let's remove the duplicates from both **df2** and **new_df**:

```
df2.drop_duplicates('Node',inplace=True)
new_df.drop_duplicates('new_Node',inplace=True, keep='last') #TODO change happens here
```

Then, ***pandas.merge()***:

```
df3 =  pd.merge(df2, new_df, how= 'left', left_on = 'Node', right_on = 'new_Node')
```

***DataFrame3***

| Node | value | new_Node | duplicates_ values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABNE | None | ABNE | 150.4 |
| VBZ3 | None | VBZ3 | 0.0 |
| ADGS | None | ADGS | 125.4 |
| EWEW | None | EWEW | 150.4 |
| DSVB | None | DSVB | 0.0 |

Now, we need to select the `duplicates_ values` and convert it into a `list` then insert it into `df2` -> `value`

```
df2['value'] = df3['duplicates_ values'].tolist()
```

***OUTPUT Of DataFrame 2***

| Node | value |
| --- | --- |
| ABNE | 150.4 |
| VBZ3 | 0.0 |
| ADGS | 125.4 |
| EWEW | 150.4 |
| DSVB | 0.0 |

Comment: the output shows that df2.node is copied to df2.value instead of copying from df1.value

Comment: thanks Dr. Xavier. Really appreciated that.

Comment: what makes it takes time is that you've data from both tables and what them to me in one table  beside the comparison of the slicing index

Comment: will be good if i can get some helps. I spent the entire weekend trying to find the solution. it works in excel with MAXIFS function. I use B1&"*" to match all characters of the df1.node longer than df2.node. "B1" is the cell contains the df2.node name i.e. "SDZX".

Comment: @Maxiloy, you can check it now, I hope that what you want 0;

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for your proposed solution which looks very useful! I never thought about concatenating the two nodes in data frame 1  before carrying out the matching with data frame 2. With the solution, can you kindly advise me (1) how to keep the duplicates with maximum value, and only remove those are not. (2) how to avoid skipping the node name in data frame 2 which has a longer character name? If I limit the character to 4, those node names with 5 character will report null.

Comment: The solution you propose can identify almost all the nodes except ZDCD where the maximum value is 150.4 but it gives 148.2. Also, the SRHNA and BANDER with longer character names in the data frame contain no value. I expect the values to be 119.7 and 148.2 respectively. Many thanks

Comment: the first question we could say we can remove `keep` parameter in `DataFrame.drop_duplicates()` you can easily remove the lowest value after sorting it. lemme edit the post. For the second question, I think you will need to adjust your data at this level. what I mean is to sort your dataframe then apply the 4 character slicing for the first 4 character name, and the others, apply on them the 5 characters. To do that will take another full-time job from one. I worked on this question more than 8 hours for now :D

Comment: Thanks Dr. Xavier. I really appreciated your help here. I will do what you‘ve suggested.

Comment: If this really helps you, please don't forget to mark it as the right answer ;)

Comment: I've edit the table, too. because it was showing the `first` duplicate not the `last`. Now, all work good!

Comment: Yes, it really helps. Thank you once again.